# Loading image in processing android

Tags: java, android, processing

I am having an issue when running the processing sketch, listed below, on my android phone and get the following error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/processing.test.sketch_230817a/files/Toyokawa-city.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

```
PImage photo;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  photo = loadImage("Toyokawa-city.jpg");
}

void draw() {
  image(photo, 0, 0);
}
```

So the question is how can I load the image in processing android?

Comment: Try placing the image in a folder called 'data' inside the sketch folder.

Comment: If you try to load an image file then it makes no sense speaking about the creation of a folder.

Comment: On my system, I get the same error message as you if I just place the image in the sketch folder.  It won't load it until I place it in a folder titled 'data' inside of the sketch folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a file in your project directory called `data` so it should look like this
`project_folder\data\Toyokawa-city.jpg`